# trouble loading JSON in AsyncTask in Fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I got 3 swipeable empty Views. The 3rd View is the "ViewAll". The first View works fine but when I swipe to the second it shows this error.

I've tried to display data that I loaded with JSON in a AsyncTask, but there is this NullPointerException error
and I don't know how to solve it...

```
11-12 10:00:23.046: E/InputEventReceiver(12007): Exception dispatching input event.
11-12 10:00:23.046: E/MessageQueue-JNI(12007): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
11-12 10:00:23.056: E/MessageQueue-JNI(12007): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 10:00:23.056: E/MessageQueue-JNI(12007):  at com.example.rumorz.ViewAll$PostTask.onPreExecute(ViewAll.java:52)
11-12 10:00:23.056: E/MessageQueue-JNI(12007):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class ViewAll extends Fragment {

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = ""; //URL to my site with JSON-code

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    private static final String TAG_message= "message";

    TextView tvuser ;
    TextView tvmessage ;

    JSONArray user = null;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new PostTask().execute();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewall, container, false);

    return rootView; 
}


private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();

             tvuser = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
         tvmessage = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvmessage);
       }

       @Override
       protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
           JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

           // Getting JSON from URL
           JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
           return json;
       }




       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
               user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                 String users = c.getString(TAG_USER);
                 String message = c.getString(TAG_message);


                tvuser.setText(users);
                tvmessage.setText(message);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
```

}

Comment: Well, your error is appenning in your `onPreExecute`.
Your should test if `getView()` is returning null. Could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread immediately after the task is executed. 
 intialize

```
tvuser = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
    tvmessage = (TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tvmessage);
```

in onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

Initialize it in `onCreateView`. Use the inflated view object to initialize your textview's. or use `getView` in `onActivityCreated` to initialize textview's.

Since the textview is declared as a class member you can use it in `onPostEecute` to set text to the same.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewall, container, false);
    tvuser = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
    tvmessage = (TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.tvmessage);

    new PostTask().execute();
    return rootView; 
}
```